# Partial copy of a stringstream

Tags: c++, c++11, stream, stringstream

How can I copy three characters beginning with the second one of *str1* to *str2*? This code doesn't work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
  std::stringstream str1("0123456789");
  std::stringstream str2;

  str1.seekg(1, str1.beg);

  std::copy(std::istream_iterator<char>(str1), std::istream_iterator<char>(str1)+3, std::ostream_iterator<char>(str2));
  std::cout << str2.str() << '\n';
}
```

The expected output is:

```
123
```

This is a dummy test, but I'd like to work with larger *stringstreams* and efficient methods.

Comment: If you want to copy exactly three characters, call `get()` three times. string stream iterators are either input iterators or output iterators, and not random access iterators.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I'd like to work with larger lengths. Is get() efficient?

Comment: No. Nothing about C++ streams is efficient. That's not what they're for. If you want efficiency you want to do something else, instead of streams.

Comment: create second ss as  `std::stringstream str2(std::string(str1.str(), 1, 3));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is another standard library algorithm called [`std::copy_n`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy_n) that will do what you want. It takes a begin iterator and the number of elements to copy. Your program works if you change the `std::copy` line to:

```
std::copy_n(std::istream_iterator<char>(str1), 3, std::ostream_iterator<char>(str2));
```

[Demo on Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/VVHDne)

An improvement might be to use [`std::next`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/next) instead of the `seekg()` to advance the first iterator to the desired offset (Thanks to Armin Montigny). That would look like:

```
std::copy_n(std::next(std::istream_iterator<char>(str1)), 3, std::ostream_iterator<char>(str2));
```

Comment: Great! I didn't know std::copy_n

Comment: You forgot ````std::next```` for the ````std::istream_iterator````. So, the correct solution is:  ````std::copy_n(std::next(std::istream_iterator<char>(str1)), 3, std::ostream_iterator<char>(str2));````. Anyway: +1

Comment: @ArminMontigny `std::next` isn't need in the code as posted. Their code uses `seekg()` to advance the stream position. We could use `std::next` instead of `seekg()` though

Comment: @Blastfurnace. You are absolutely correct. Sorry, but I always think in one-liners . . .

Comment: And for raw data:  `std::copy_n(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(str1), 3, std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(str2));`

Answer (score 0):

Use `substr()` of `std::string`. To use the it for `std::stringstream` use str1.str()
Then assign it to `str::string` str2.

Step 1: Take the string our of the `std::stringstream`.

Step 2: Perform the operation on `std::string`.

Step 3: Assign the string to `std::stringstream`

Other way to **get the part of stringstream**:

```
char c[10] = {};
std::istringstream input("This is sample text."); // std::stringbuf makes its entire
                                                  // buffer available for unblocking read
input.readsome(c, 5); // reads 'This ' and stores in c[0] .. c[4]
input.readsome(c, 9); // reads 'is sample' and stores in c[0] .. c[8]
```

Comment: Can I convert a only some characters from stringstream to string? Is this method efficient with very large streams?

Comment: char c[10] = {};
    std::istringstream input("This is sample text."); // std::stringbuf makes its entire
                                                      // buffer available for unblocking read
    input.readsome(c, 5); // reads 'This ' and stores in c[0] .. c[4]
    input.readsome(c, 9); // reads 'is sample' and stores in c[0] .. c[8]
    std::cout << c;